# Deal with new line character “\n” in Sqlite database using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Sqlite database named test.db, which contains two tables with structures like this:

Table1: ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name varchar(500), Color varchar(500)

Table2: ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name varchar(500), Smell varchar(500)

I am trying to join two tables using the following code

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db') 
with con: 
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT Color, Smell FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.Name = Table2.Name")
```

However, I failed because Table1.Name has invisible new line character “\n” inserted, while Table2.Name doesn’t, so the WHERE clause doesn’t work.

Is there a way to modify the SELECT statement a little bit so that Table1.Name = Table2.Name will work? Or do I have to regenerate Table1 to remove “\n”, but I don’t know how?

Comment: In other words the data in your table is incorrect? Do _not_ hack around with your code to fix the database; you'll be in huge amounts of trouble later down the line (20th time there's something wrong?). The only way to fix the database is to do so. Your data-model is a little strange as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `replace()` SQL function:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Color, Smell FROM Table1, Table2 "
            "WHERE replace(Table1.Name, '\n', '') = Table2.Name")
```

You can update your whole `Table` `Name` column to remove the newline characters altogether:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET Name = replace(Name, '\n', '') "
            "WHERE Name like '%\n%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is fix your tables so that the data is correct for your application. It looks like you have data like `Apple\n` in your table's `name` column.

Run this query to fix your table:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Name = rtrim(Name,'\n')
```

That will remove all `\n` from the right side of the value of the `Name` column in each row, and then update that row.

Edit:
  @Martijn's answer will allow your query to work (assuming you don't have the same problem with `Table2.Name`), but you should really fix the data in your tables so that you don't have to remember to do these workarounds everytime.