# Random newline characters appearing in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

**The problem**

I am currently having a problem with lists. Whenever I get data from the table students(the classes) and put it into a list. I am using the following line of code to do this

```
classes = [list(i) for i in query("SELECT class FROM students GROUP BY class").fetchall()]
```

*The table students contains*

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID |  name   | class |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | John    |   901 |
|  2 | Pat     |   904 |
|  3 | Hal     |   911 |
|  4 | Bill    |   905 |
|  5 | Lyon    |   902 |
|  6 | Lauren  |   907 |
|  7 | Phillip |   908 |
|  8 | Charlie |   906 |
|  9 | Amy     |   911 |
| 10 | Paul    |   904 |
| 11 | Lewis   |   903 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

However when I

```
print(classes)
```

The result is

```
[['901\n'], ['902'], ['903\n'], ['904'], ['905'], ['906'], ['907'], ['908'], ['911\n']]
```

**Question**

Why are the new line characters there and is there a way to get rid of them? I would have thought this

```
for e in classes:
        e = str(e).replace("\n", ' ')
```

would have worked for replacing but it appears it is not working.

Comment: The data *in sqlite* contains those newlines.

Comment: is there any way of avoiding this using sqlite?

Comment: See [Deal with new line character “\n” in Sqlite database using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18942258)

Answer (score 0):

you can not convert list to string. Use `enumerate` to access the index of any entry in each loop , and also as `classes` is a nested list you need to use index `j[0]` for access to entries :

```
for i,j in enumerate(classes):
    if '\n' in j[0]:
        classes[i] = str(j[0]).replace("\n", ' ')
```

Then result should be :

```
['901','902','903',.....]
```